# Jquery, HTML, CSS Why does my "Auto" .heat-icon-parent does not inherit the same color as my "heat" and "cool" color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, jquery-ui

So recently I tried making a mode function that changes color when I click on different mode there are ("Cool", "Heat", "Fan", "Dry", "Auto") and lets say I assigned a color for each of them example: Cool = Blue , Heat = Orange etc.

Based on the exact css, functions and event listener I provide why im facing this problem:

- The .heat-icon-parent for the word "Auto" does not inherit the same color of .heat-icon-parent for the word "heat"? like if I last click on heat the color is orange i want my auto also to be orange and when i click cool and color is blue i want my auto when click is blue too.

this is my code:

```
// Variable to store the last clicked mode
    var lastClickedMode = 'cool-mode';

    // Mode Toggle
    $('.heat-icon-parent').click(modeToggle);
    $('.heat-icon-parent#cool-mode').addClass('clicked');
    $('.heat-icon-parent').click(modeColor);

    // Set the fill color based on the 'clicked' class for all SVG paths
    $('.heat-icon-parent svg path').css('fill', function () {
        return $(this).closest('.heat-icon-parent').hasClass('clicked') ? '#ffff' : '#AEAEAE';
    });


function modeToggle() {
    // Check if this element is already clicked
    var isClicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');

    // Remove 'clicked' class from all elements
    $('.heat-icon-parent#cool-mode, .heat-icon-parent#heat-mode, .heat-icon-parent#fan-mode, .heat-icon-parent#dry-mode, .heat-icon-parent#auto-mode').removeClass('clicked');

    // Set the fill color based on the 'clicked' class for all SVG paths
    $('.heat-icon-parent svg path').css('fill', '#AEAEAE');

    // Toggle the 'clicked' class only if it wasn't already clicked
    if (!isClicked) {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        // Update the last clicked mode
        lastClickedMode = $(this).attr('id');
        // Set the fill color for the clicked element
        $(this).find('svg path').css('fill', '#ffff');
    }
}

function modeColor() {
    $('.heat-icon-parent').css('background', '');

    // Get the mode associated with the clicked element
    var mode = $(this).attr('id');

    // Update the background color based on the mode
    switch (mode) {
        case 'cool-mode':
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background', 'linear-gradient(141.67deg, #56aff3, #1c71c8)');
            break;
        case 'heat-mode':
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background', 'linear-gradient(141.67deg, #FF8D5D, #e67e22)');
            break;
        case 'fan-mode':
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background', 'linear-gradient(141.67deg, lime, green');
            break;
        case 'dry-mode':
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background', 'linear-gradient(141.67deg, #00BCB5, teal)');
            break;
        case 'auto-mode':
            // Inherit the color of the last clicked mode for auto-mode
            var lastClickedModeColor = $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background');
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked#auto-mode').css('background', lastClickedModeColor);
            break;
        default:
            // Default background color
            $('.heat-icon-parent.clicked').css('background', 'linear-gradient(141.67deg, #56aff3, #1c71c8)');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One thing I see in `modeToggle()` is it is too ambiguous. For example, you have `var isClicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');`, yet it is not clear what `this` is in reference to; cause it would be in reference to the function and not an element in the page. Please provide a [mcve].